# Initialise semaphores using sem_open

Tags: c, semaphore

In my producer and consumer problem, I use `sem_open()` to initialize the semaphores. How could I test if `sem_open()` works in a correct way?

The program can be compiled, but when I run the program it does not print anything. I test the program and found the problem maybe about `sem_open()`. I find if I comment the `sem_open()` in the program, the program will run correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
pthread_t pro_thread, con_thread;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int counter = 0;
sem_t  *empty, *full;

void print_buffer(int counter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i ++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void* producer(void* var) {
    int item;
    while(1) {
        item = rand() % 100 + 1;
        sem_wait(empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while (counter == BUFFER_SIZE)
            ; // waiting

        if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
            buffer[counter] = item;
            counter ++;
            printf("Producer: ");
            print_buffer(counter);
        }

        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(full);
    }
}
 
void* consumer(void* var) {
    int item;
    while(1) {
        sem_wait(full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        
        while (counter == 0)
            ; // waiting
        
        if(counter > 0) {
            counter --;
            print_buffer(counter);
        }

        sleep(1);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(empty);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    empty = sem_open("/mysem", O_CREAT, 0644, BUFFER_SIZE);
    full = sem_open("/mysem", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

    pthread_create(&pro_thread, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&con_thread, NULL, consumer, NULL);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using the same semaphore (`/mysem`) for both full and empty? That doesn't look logically correct.

Comment: I don't know where is the file of the semaphore, so I searched online and one example said /mysem will store the semaphore. I'm not sure what should the file be.

Comment: Perhaps you should go back to read the [sem_open man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open). It answers the questions you have asked so far. In particular, opening a semaphore with the same name yields the same semaphore. That's not what you want for this program. Instead, you may want to for example open `"/full_sem"` for one and `"/empty_sem"` for the other.

Comment: @kaylum I try to change the name of the semaphores to /empty and /full. The program run correctly. So the first variable in sem_open() is the semaphore name, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [sem_open man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open):

> The semaphore is identified by name.

Since your code provides the same name value (`/mysem`) for both `sem_open` calls it results in referencing the same semaphore for both full and empty. That's clearly not what the logic of the program should be. Instead, open different semaphores for each. It's also best practice to check the return values of all function calls.

```
empty = sem_open("/empty_sem", O_CREAT, 0644, BUFFER_SIZE);
if (empty == SEM_FAILED) {
     perror("Failed to open semphore for empty");
     exit(-1);
}

full = sem_open("/full_sem", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
if (full == SEM_FAILED) {
     sem_close(empty);
     perror("Failed to open semphore for full");
     exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Are empty and full semaphores created every time when I run the code? Because today I run the code and the code print nothing, if I change the semaphore name to `/empty` and `/full`, the code will run correctly. It can be compiled.

Comment: I just use `sem_unlink` to prevent the name has been used. It works.